# select2 4 and bs3 modals - z-index issue?

Tags: jquery-select2-4

In the process of switching from select2 3.5 -> 4.0.  I have now come across a situation where there are problems when used in boostrap modals.

In 3.5 I used something like this which allowed them to function properly :

```
.modal-open .select2-drop-mask {
  z-index: 10051;
}

.modal-open .select2-drop {
  z-index: 10052;
}

.modal-open .select2-search {
  z-index: 10053;
}
```

The classes and quite a bit else has changed with 4.0 and this no longer does anything.  I am assuming the issue is z-index related, but am not sure.  I have tested the same `select` outside of the modal and it works as intended which is why I am assuming it is css related.  The input shows, but the dropdown, search etc do not.  Has anyone else come across this and found the solution?

**EDIT jsfiddle:**

This is a little different than my use case - I use `load()` to inject remote content into the modal then show it in, BUT the same issue happens here.  You cannot gain focus on the search input to type anything.  Strangely enough I noticed it works in Internet Explorer 11, but does not in the latest Firefox, Chrome, or Safari.

[modal fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5n590cq/6/)

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this problem.
You just remove 'tabindex="-1" '  in modal  div:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```